# Dual boot Windows and Fedora on separate drives

Tags: windows, fedora

I upgraded my laptop with SSD and installed the HDD to the optical disk drive space using an ODD caddy. I installed Fedora OS on the HDD (disk 1) and Windows on SSD (disk 0). I'm able to boot into Windows without getting an option to boot into Fedora.

I'm thinking of installing a grub menu via Windows, however I have no idea how to do that.

Windows Disk Management:

[image]

Comment: If the system booting using GRUB ?

Comment: Yes, I just re installed fedora on the secondary hard drive with boot loader installed to the primary. Now, I'm able to boot via grub menu, but still no option to boot to the secondary drive which has fedora installed

Answer (score 0):

GRUB is a complex piece of software. I suggest that you to read the manual. Here only few suggestions.

While running in Linux, enter "lsblk --fs" and note the UUID of the partitions you want to boot from. Then try to generate a scratch GRUB config using "grub2-mkconfig -o your_scratch_file". Examine this file in order to see if it contains the entries which you need. If this seems OK, you can try to install this file to /boot/grub2/grub.cfg and you can try to boot the system. This is a simple but dangerous way. A more secure but more complex way is to use the GRUB command mode in order to test the new config. Put the generated config file to /root/tentative.cfg. Then boot the system. When the GRUB menu appears, enter "c" in order to enter the command mode. If necessary, enter "insmod part_gpt" if you have a GPT partitioning.
Then enter "search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root the-UUID-of-the-partition-of-the-fedora-where-/-is-mounted". Remember the previous output of "lsblk --fs". Then enter "configfile $(root)/root/tentative.cfg". This should start the booting using the tentative config. If this tentative config is OK, you can copy it to /boot/grub2/grub.cfg, which is its "normal" location.